# What model of multiple regression do I use to see if two independent variables affect a dependent variable, I also need to use two dummy variables?

Tags: r, self-study, multiple-regression

I need to explore the determinants of wheat yield using multiple regression. There are 120 observations. Do I need to use ANOVA? I am using R studio. My results need to include a consideration of more than one functional form, one or more interaction terms for a select set of variables, and the use of dummy variables.

Variable Descriptions:

```
yld wheat yield in kg/ha  
R Growing season rainfall (mm)  
N nitrogen fertilization rate (kg/ha)  
PrevCereal 1 if precious crop was a cereal, 0 otherwise  
RegionCode Location code (0/1)
```

Comment: It's all just multiple regression, but some people might refer to this kind of thing as ANCOVA I guess. ... Is this homework?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought I would need to use a two way ANOVA? It's an assignment for university.

Comment: The use of dummy variables doesn't change the method of analysis, really. ANOVA and ANCOVA and multiple regression are all the same model; in matrix algebra form $Y = XB + e$

Comment: You should first read up on what ANOVA/ANCOVA really is before going further. There's a number of documents that wheel-train you through regression using R, this one being only one of them: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Just a simple guide as it's an assignment - don't want to ruin all the fun.

I often use the [rms](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/index.html) package.

1. Enter your model with splines for the continuous variables (use the `rcs()` spline as it works best with the `rms` package) and any possible interactions.
2. Check the general model assumptions - if you have issues try bootstrapping with the `bootcov()` function
3. Check overall ANOVA with the `anova()` function in the `rms` package, it has very nice built-in tests for non-linearity that are very useful.
4. Rebuild your model depending on the ANOVA results

Hope this helps!